# Text color animation

Tags: android

Is there a way to animate a text color change (from anycolor to white)?

The only variant I came up with, is placing two textviews (with the same text) in one place, and fading the top one, so the bottom one (that has a white color) will become visible.

P.S. I scrapped the variant of the 2 TextViews since it looked weird (edges weren't smooth and, since I have a lot of such elements on the screen it was really lagging the scrolling). What I did, was a crazy hack that does the animation with the use of a Thread and setTextColor (that also forces redraw of a textview).

Since I needed only 2 color changes (from red to white, and from green to white) I hardcoded the values and all of the transition colors between them. So here's how it looks:

```
public class BlinkingTextView extends TextView {
public BlinkingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void animateBlink(final boolean red) {
    if (animator != null) {
        animator.drop();
    }
    animator = new Animator(this, red);
    animator.start();
}

public void clearBlinkAnimation() {
    if (animator != null) {
        animator.drop();
    }
}

private Animator animator;

private final static class Animator extends Thread {
    public Animator(final TextView textView, final boolean red) {
        this.textView = textView;
        if (red) {
            SET_TO_USE = RED;
        } else {
            SET_TO_USE = GREEN;
        }
    }

    private TextView textView;

    private final int[] SET_TO_USE;

    private final static int[] RED = {
        -2142396,
        -2008754,
        -1874854,
        -1740697,
        -1540490,
        -1405563,
        -1205099,
        -1004634,
        -804170,
        -669243,
        -469036,
        -334879,
        -200979,
        -67337,
        -1
    };
    private final static int[] GREEN = {
        -6959821,
        -6565826,
        -6106293,
        -5646758,
        -5055894,
        -4530309,
        -3939444,
        -3283042,
        -2692177,
        -2166592,
        -1575728,
        -1116193,
        -656660,
        -262665,
        -1
    };

    private boolean stop;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 15) {
            if (stop) break;
            final int color = SET_TO_USE[i];
            if (stop) break;
            textView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!stop) {
                        textView.setTextColor(color);                       
                    }
                }
            });
            if (stop) break;
            i++;
            if (stop) break;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(66);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            if (stop) break;
        }
    }

    public void drop() {
        stop = true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't found a totally distinct method, I have tried to use a [TextSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html) (with the fade animation) to create the colour-change effect. A `TextSwitcher` is a kind of `ViewSwitcher` which literally animates between two (internal) `TextView`s. Did you manually implement the same system unknowingly? ;) It manages a bit more of the process for you, so you may find it easier to work with (especially if you want to try more involved animations). I would create new subclass of `TextSwitcher` and some methods e.g. `setColour()` which can set the new colour and then trigger an animation. The animation code can then be moved outside of your main application.

- make sure you keep a handle on the two `TextView`s that are put into the switcher
- change the colour of the other `TextView` and call `setText()` to animate between them

If you are already using a `ViewSwitcher` then I don't think there is an easier way to implement this.

Comment: Thanks. I actually haven't implemented the method I was talking about (just thought about it). Thanks a lot, I will try your method now :)

Answer (score 56):

You can use new [Property Animation Api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) for color animation:

```
Integer colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
Integer colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        textView.setTextColor((Integer)animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }

});
colorAnimation.start();
```

For backward compatability with Android 2.x use [Nine Old Androids library](http://nineoldandroids.com/) from Jake Wharton.

Answer (score 44):

The Easiest solution will be to use Object Animators :

```
ObjectAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(yourTextView, "textColor",
            Color.RED, Color.GREEN);
            colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
            colorAnim.start();
```

Comment: how to control the speed of the objectanimator?

Comment: @pollaris set the duration `colorAnim.setDuration(1000);`

Comment: Perfect solution, I used it to make nicely animated click effects with a soft fade out on text views, because the default behaviour with a color selector was too fast and looked ugly

Answer (score 3):

No need to keep handles to the two text views. First add the fadeIn/fadeOut animations:

```
textSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
textSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
```

then:

```
TextView currentTextView = (TextView)(textSwitcher.getNextView().equals(
  textSwitcher.getChildAt(0)) ? 
  textSwitcher.getChildAt(1) : textSwitcher.getChildAt(0)
);
// setCurrentText() first to be the same as newText if you need to
textSwitcher.setTextColor(fadeOutColor);
((TextView) textSwitcher.getNextView()).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
textSwitcher.setText(newText);
```

Just implemented it like this so proven to work.

Answer (score 3):

best way use ValueAnimator and ColorUtils.blendARGB

```
 ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
 valueAnimator.setDuration(325);
 valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

              float fractionAnim = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

              textView.setTextColor(ColorUtils.blendARGB(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")
                                    , Color.parseColor("#000000")
                                    , fractionAnim));
        }
});
valueAnimator.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

As others mention, using `ObjectAnimator` solves for this.  However, in the existing posts - I wasn't seeing how to set duration. For me the color change would happen immediately.

The solution below shows:

1. setting the animation with some interval; thanks to post: https://plus.google.com/+CyrilMottier/posts/X4yoNHHszwq
2. a way to continuously cycle back and forth between the 2 colors

---

```
void animateTextViewColors(TextView textView, Integer colorTo) {

    final Property<TextView, Integer> property = new Property<TextView, Integer>(int.class, "textColor") {
        @Override
        public Integer get(TextView object) {
            return object.getCurrentTextColor();
        }

        @Override
        public void set(TextView object, Integer value) {
            object.setTextColor(value);
        }
    };

    final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(textView, property, colorTo);
    animator.setDuration(8533L);
    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
    animator.start();
}

void oscillateDemo(final TextView textView) {

    final int whiteColor = ContextCompat.getColor(TheApp.getAppContext(), R.color.white);
    final int yellowColor = ContextCompat.getColor(TheApp.getAppContext(), R.color.yellow);

    final int counter = 100;

    Thread oscillateThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

                final int fadeToColor = (i % 2 == 0)
                        ? yellowColor
                        : whiteColor;

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        animateTextViewColors(textView, fadeToColor);
                    }
                });                                      

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2450);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException iEx) {}
            }
        }
    };

    oscillateThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I scrapped the variant of the 2 TextViews since it looked weird (edges weren't smooth and, since I have a lot of such elements on the screen it was really lagging the scrolling). What I did, was a crazy hack that does the animation with the use of a Thread and setTextColor (that also forces redraw of a textview).

Since I needed only 2 color changes (from red to white, and from green to white) I hardcoded the values and all of the transition colors between them. So here's how it looks:

```
public class BlinkingTextView extends TextView {
public BlinkingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void animateBlink(final boolean red) {
    if (animator != null) {
        animator.drop();
    }
    animator = new Animator(this, red);
    animator.start();
}

public void clearBlinkAnimation() {
    if (animator != null) {
        animator.drop();
    }
}

private Animator animator;

private final static class Animator extends Thread {
    public Animator(final TextView textView, final boolean red) {
        this.textView = textView;
        if (red) {
            SET_TO_USE = RED;
        } else {
            SET_TO_USE = GREEN;
        }
    }

    private TextView textView;

    private final int[] SET_TO_USE;

    private final static int[] RED = {
        -2142396,
        -2008754,
        -1874854,
        -1740697,
        -1540490,
        -1405563,
        -1205099,
        -1004634,
        -804170,
        -669243,
        -469036,
        -334879,
        -200979,
        -67337,
        -1
    };
    private final static int[] GREEN = {
        -6959821,
        -6565826,
        -6106293,
        -5646758,
        -5055894,
        -4530309,
        -3939444,
        -3283042,
        -2692177,
        -2166592,
        -1575728,
        -1116193,
        -656660,
        -262665,
        -1
    };

    private boolean stop;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 15) {
            if (stop) break;
            final int color = SET_TO_USE[i];
            if (stop) break;
            textView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!stop) {
                        textView.setTextColor(color);                       
                    }
                }
            });
            if (stop) break;
            i++;
            if (stop) break;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(66);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            if (stop) break;
        }
    }

    public void drop() {
        stop = true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found with valueAnimator as well as ObjectAnimator is that the animator iterates through a number of random colors, and the transition doesn't look smooth. I wrote the following code which worked smoothly. Hope it helps someone else also.

```
public static void changeTextColor(final TextView textView, int startColor, int endColor,
                                   final long animDuration, final long animUnit){
    if (textView == null) return;

    final int startRed = Color.red(startColor);
    final int startBlue = Color.blue(startColor);
    final int startGreen = Color.green(startColor);

    final int endRed = Color.red(endColor);
    final int endBlue = Color.blue(endColor);
    final int endGreen = Color.green(endColor);

    new CountDownTimer(animDuration, animUnit){
        //animDuration is the time in ms over which to run the animation
        //animUnit is the time unit in ms, update color after each animUnit

        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            int red = (int) (endRed + (l * (startRed - endRed) / animDuration));
            int blue = (int) (endBlue + (l * (startBlue - endBlue) / animDuration));
            int green = (int) (endGreen + (l * (startGreen - endGreen) / animDuration));

            textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(endRed, endGreen, endBlue));
        }
    }.start();
}
```