# AnimationDrawable on TextView?

Tags: android, android-animation

for a TextView, we can apply such as LinearGradient to the text's foreground.

is there a method to set a AnimationDrawable for a TextView?

Comment: textView.setBackground(background); it will apply to the text view.

Comment: View.setBackgroundDrawable() ?

Comment: actually i want to set the foreground color (textcolor) for the textview

Comment: so what do you want AnimarionDrawable or FG text color?

Comment: no no, i mean set AnimationDrawable to the TextColor of TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Heyy, i found these links here:

[Text color animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655326/text-color-animation)

[Using a ValueAnimator to make a TextView blink different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582434/using-a-valueanimator-to-make-a-textview-blink-different-colors)

Is this what you are looking for ?