# Fadein Only the Button Text in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, button

I used the following code to fade in only the `Button` Text. but it gives fadein for whole `Button`.

```
Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);

//register btn listener
    m_btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            m_btn_register.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);

        }
    });
```

**fade_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.1"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="2000"
    />
</set>
```

what is the correct way to acheive this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text color animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655326/text-color-animation)

Comment: Do you want each character of the text to fade in?

Comment: No whole text like `this is my string`

Comment: okay. this can be done with spannable string. let me post my solution

Comment: Okay post your answer. And I'll check.

Comment: Posted a snap shot see if that is exactly what you want

Comment: I'll check on Monday. Then let u know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note : Having custom spans for button does not work on lollipop and above. So have this

```
 <Button
    android:textAllCaps="false"
```

My CustomSpan

```
public class CustomSpan extends CharacterStyle implements UpdateAppearance {

    private int alpha;

    public int getAlpha() {
        return alpha;
    }

    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    public CustomSpan() {

    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint paint) {
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);

    }
}
```

Custom Property

```
 private static final Property<CustomSpan, Integer> FADE_INT_PROPERTY
        = new Property<CustomSpan, Integer>(Integer.class, "FADE_INT_PROPERTY") {

    @Override
    public void set(CustomSpan span, Integer value) {
        span.setAlpha(value);
    }
    @Override
    public Integer get(CustomSpan object) {
        return object.getAlpha();
    }
};
```

Then

```
String text = button.getText().toString();

final CustomSpan span = new CustomSpan();
final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);

int start = 0;
int end = text.length();
spannableString.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
                    span, FADE_INT_PROPERTY, 0, 255);
            objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new IntEvaluator());
            objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    button.setText(spannableString);
                }
            });
            objectAnimator.setDuration(10000);
            objectAnimator.start();

        }
    });
```

Gif [image]

Comment: I saw your output snap. This is what I exactly want. Many thanks. I'll check on Monday then I'll confirm you.

Comment: Cool. I had the solution hours before. The only problem i faced was spans din't work on lollipop and above. So was stuck. Then i came to know that in lollipop they remove custom spans in button to meet material design guidelines. Don't forget to the check the note. Also check the api that your targeting.

Comment: I'm targeting Marshmallow. Is not possible?

Comment: Works .But had to add  `<Button
    android:textAllCaps="false"`. Read the note in the post

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
           android:pivotX="50.0%"
           android:pivotY="50.0%"
           android:fromXScale="1.0"
           android:toXScale="0.9"
           android:fromYScale="1.0"
           android:toYScale="0.9"/>
    <alpha android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:fromAlpha="1.0"
            android:toAlpha="0.7"/>
</set>
```

and one more thing declare `Animation` gloabal.

Comment: this is also animate whole view. i need to animate only the button text

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution using **animation API** because it works on the **view** and doesn't take care of the content of it.

So, I think you should create **container view** for the button and add your button background for the new container.
then set the button background to be transparent.

After that make the animation for the **button** only.