# How to make moving animation in TabLayout

Tags: android

Sample Gif:[image]

I want to make TabLayout moving animation effect same as sample gif. In this sample the TabLayout consists two tabs (Income, Expense). On right or left swipe it gets change their background colour. How can i do that.

I've made TabLayout with ViewPager successfully. I've no idea to make this type of animation. Kindly help.

TabLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Comment: I would say you don't need a TabLayout to achieve that effect. Maybe a toggle button and no left/right swipe would do the trick.

Comment: any example like that?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a big question but I suggest you start with creating the custom View for the tabs. see [Tab.setCustomView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(int))

Second you should handle the animation, probably with the scroll offset of the viewPager. [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrolled(int, float, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrolled(int,%20float,%20int))

You're going to want to use positionOffset to update the position and color of the selector.

Hope this gives you a direction to how to accomplish this.

Comment: any example like that?

Comment: i've a part of solution. Increase height of tabIndicator as it filled height of TabLaout. By this we can achieve transition effect but the problem is the text of TabLayout gets invisible. I dont know how to make it visible.

Comment: what u say about my solution?

Comment: That's a possibility, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655326/text-color-animation This should help with the color transition.